# java Facebook integration

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

In java facebook integrated using restfb.somewhere it is written that restfb is deprecated.then what to use in that case.I don't want to use third party.Is there any guide to follow up to use facebook open graph in java application.

Comment: **spring social** is good framework to integrate a bunch of social websites. I think thrid-parties are ok, actually, the third parties are the real driving wheel for integrating with social networks.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your pom.xml, it's easy to integrate with facebook and others:

```
    <!-- Spring Social -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Facebook API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.social-facebook-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.social-facebook-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

See [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) to learn more

Comment: But third parties are not secure.

Comment: No matter `the third` or `the provider-provided`, they all follow OAuth1/2 and are open source which you can review. I don't know what you exactly mean by `not secure`. But it's ok, if you really emotionmally love provider-provided SDKs. the provider-provided SDK  is always not elegant as the third parties are. and always low level and not abstract one. I suggest you try both and judge it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I will definitely try both

Comment: :). If you are integrating with not only Facebook, but also others like twitter, github, pinterest. Spring social is better choice. Actually, the social networks are aligning with spring social framework. Good luck1

Comment: yes I want to integrate with Facebook,twitter,pinterest,tumblr and instagram. But if in future the user for my site will increase are the third party going to charge for that..

Comment: so many sites is connecting social sites as you are, so the community are very active and positive. you don't need to warry about it. the SDKs envolve fast aligning the social networks' APIs. they will change together.